How can I get a video thumbnail from VK.com (Vkontakte)?
Preferably with JavaScript on the client side, but with PHP on the server if that's not possible.
I know there's a video.get method in their API that returns an "items" array containing an "image" array of preview images of various widths. But the docs claim that you need a "user access token" to use it, which can be gotten with "implicit flow" (this seems to involve opening a popup window and making the user login to VK) or "authorization code flow" (which is from the server-side, but also involves the user logging in, as far as I can tell).
I don't want to make the user log in. And there must be some way, since other sites that get VK video thumbnails don't require a user login - for example, Google in the "Videos" tab shows videos from VK.com with thumbnails. Another example is the ImgPanda VK video thumbnail downloader, which gets a thumbnail after the user enters a VK video URL, after a few seconds of waiting, and apparently with no login.
I came across a video-thumbnails GitHub project that has some PHP code that seems relevant. It seems that in a VK embedded iframe video, the thumbnail is src of the img tag with an id of "player_thumb" (which I also saw was true by inspecting the contents of the iframe with developer tools in the browser).
I would've preferred to use the API, but I thought I'd try the following GET request with VSCode REST client:
GET https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-135285&id=456240123&js_api=0
That actually worked two weeks ago (it returned the source code of a VK video embed), but now I get "413 Request Entity Too Large".
When it WAS working, I wrote some quick JavaScript+Regex to try and get the thumbnail src:
function fetchVkThumbnail (oid,id) {
    const vkThumbnailRegex = /background-image:url\((?<thumbnail>.+\.jpg)\)/;

    return fetch(`https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-${oid}&id=${id}`)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then((text) => {
            const thumbnailSrc = text.match(vkThumbnailRegex).groups.thumbnail;
            console.log(thumbnailSrc);
            return thumbnailSrc;
        });
}

...but it gave the error message Access to fetch at 'https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-135285&id=456240123' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Also, I found an interesting discussion about how openID and oAuth work in VK. Not sure if relevant.

Make requests from server (from PHP for example)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Yeah, I ended up scraping the thumbnail URL server-side from that "video_ext.php" URL mentioned in my question (using the same regex, but in PHP instead of JavaScript). It doesn't seem possible to do it client-side at the moment. But it's pretty fast, quicker than getting a thumbnail client-side from the YouTube API.
